# tomcat deploy wars outside webapps

Tags: tomcat

Friends: (Thanks in advance for your help)

We are trying to deploy war files outside of the webapps folder.  The war file name is xyz.war.  The approach is the xyz.xml in the conf/Catalina/localhost folder.  In that file the docBase is set to /opt/testing/mywebapps/xyz

The xyz.war is located or placed in the folder /opt/testing/mywebapps folder.

The deployment happens but the unarchiving of the war file is not.  When I go to the work folder, I see the xyz.war file unarchived but I dont see the WEB-INF/web.xml file along with a few other missing jsp files as well.  Essentially the unarchiving of the .war file is not occuring correctly.

Not sure what attributes tot he  element I am missing or what nested elements I am supposed to put.

==================

When I unarchive the xyz.war by myself in the /opt/testing/mywebapps folder then the app seems to work.

So what gives ?

Kindly help.

-N

Answer (score 0):

WAR files located outside the Host's appBase are not unpacked into the appBase.

See https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51294 for further details.

The feature will probably be added to Tomcat 7 in a couple of releases time.